# how to stop saving thumbnails in ~/.thumbnails

Tags: thumbnails

File manager keeps thumbnails in `~/.thumbnails` even after the original photo is deleted.

It's really annoying and I feel like it's insecure if some one can see a photo that I've deleted. I want this folder to be clear. I don't mind if it takes time to show thumbnails of photos. How can I stop thumbnails being saved?

Comment: If you're concerned that people may be watching your `~/.thumbnails` then you should also be concerned that they may be watching your images that resulted in the creation of thumbnail files in the first place. The solution to that is usually, depending on the situation and your threat model, discretionary user access control or file or disk encryption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open file manager (Nautilus), then **Edit > Preferences**, and a small window will open like this:

[image: Nautilus file manager]

Set **show thumbnails** to **never**

After this delete all files in the `~/.thumbnails` folder to make sure that all thumbnails are deleted and never created again

Comment: then it's stop showing thumbnails not saving.. i want it to show thumbnails but not to save

Comment: @Srinesh what you said just now is not possible. it can be only one thing. thumbnails will only show when they are saved. this is how every OS works

Answer (score 12):

***Requires root permissions***

I solved this using [`tmpfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs).
The thumbnails remain in RAM until the next reboot and are recreated if needed again.
Following two lines in `/etc/fstab` create `tmpfs` for both thumbnails directories:

```
none /home/username/.thumbnails tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,uid=1000,gid=1000,mode=0755 0 0
none /home/username/.cache/thumbnails tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,uid=1000,gid=1000,mode=0755 0 0
```

Replace **`username`** with your user name and **`1000`** with your UID and GID. (You can find these by executing the `id` in shell).

Now clear the directories and mount `tmpfs` to them.

```
rm -rf /home/username/.thumbnails/*
sudo mount /home/username/.thumbnails
rm -rf /home/username/.cache/thumbnails/*
sudo mount /home/username/.cache/thumbnails
```

Comment: This is an absolutely perfect solution and should be marked as an answer instead of the current one.

Comment: right, I think so too.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy, make thumbnails folder as readable only.
You can do it only by sudo.
You will have your thumbs in RAM only!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.) Also, isn't this precisely what [lukasrozs' answer suggests](/a/809084/175814)?

Answer (score 1):

## Temp thumbnail Cache using Systemd

I wanted to give a systemd update to this. This is just taking what @lukasrozs already said here https://askubuntu.com/a/809084/1242385 but uses systemd mounts rather than modifying /etc/fstab.

I'm going to assume your thumbnail cache is in a directory like `/home/dephekt/.cache/thumbnails` and that the user you want to mount this for is UID & GID 1000.

### The unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Thumbnailer Cache tmpfs mount
ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=!/home/dephekt/.cache/thumbnails
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=local-fs.target umount.target
After=swap.target

[Mount]
What=tmpfs
Where=/home/dephekt/.cache/thumbnails
Type=tmpfs
Options=rw,mode=1755,relatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,size=512M,uid=1000,gid=1000

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
```

### Mount size

You can modify the `size=256M` mount option to be whatever size you think is sufficient for the thumbnailer cache. I set this to 512M, since my the default maximum cache size for me is 512M. You can find that setting by doing:

```bash
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.thumbnail-cache maximum-size
512
```

### Unit file naming

The file needs to be named using the path you used in the `Where=` argument above, but properly escaped. In my case, the `Where=` path is `/home/dephekt/.cache/thumbnails`. To easily determine how systemd would want this to look escaped, you can do:

```bash
$ systemd-escape --path --suffix=mount "/home/dephekt/.cache/thumbnails"
home-dephekt-.cache-thumbnails.mount
```

That gives you exactly what the filename should look like.

### Placement & installation

Then place the file in `/etc/systemd/system` and run:

```bash
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable home-dephekt-.cache-thumbnails.mount
sudo systemctl start home-dephekt-.cache-thumbnails.mount
```

This should cause the mount to happen right now and also automatically after booting.