# How to automatic mount a tmpfs directory

Tags: mount, fstab, tmpfs

I read about a configuration to load the directory `~/.cache/thumbnails/` to `tmpfs`

https://askubuntu.com/a/809084

With this lines in /etc/fstab

```
none /home/username/.cache/thumbnails tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,uid=1000,gid=1000,mode=0755 0 0
```

But when I log in ubuntu it doesn't mount the directory automatically, I need to run `mount` every time.

Comment: Do you have output upon the command "sudo mount -a"? If yes, there is an error. Commonly I see that the first entry is `tmpfs` instead of `none`, so eventually try changing that,

Comment: I wonder what you did when I saw this command in fstab, but it actually works, I will swap the directory and tmpfs command.

tmpfs /home/max/.cache/thumbnails tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,uid=1001,gid=1002,mode=0755 0 0

Comment: It didin't work but I found another command

Comment: tmpfs        /home/max/.cache/thumbnails    tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777   0  0

Comment: But the size of tmpfs is very high 5GB, I would like that value to be smaller

Comment: That will be another question. Current question is on how to automount a tmpfs directory.